# New laptop install not recognising GTX980M

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit on my laptop, which has an internal Intel video for the internal monitor and a GeForce GTX980M for an external monitor.

Unfortunately Ubuntu does not see the GeForce card at all.

I have a Windows install alongside Ubuntu and the card works fine if I load up in Windows.

I have downloaded the latest driver but can't figure out how to install it. Usually people give a summarised description of what to do, but being an Ubuntu noob I need details :(

What steps do I need to do to install this driver - bearing in mind, so far the GTX card is not recognised at all so has no drivers installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your new Nvidia adapter needs new drivers. You can install them by running in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

and reboot.

The driver that comes with Ubuntu 14.04.3 `nvidia-340` or the previous `nvidia-331` do not support that adapter.

Comment: Just a note that I just checked the Wily packages (15.10) and it looks like `nvidia-346` is included. According to [this](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/81252/en-us), 346.35 added support for GTX 980M. So, 15.10 looks like it will support the GPU.

Comment: nvidia-346 is included in 14.04 and 15.04 too. And probably it does support 980M.

Comment: Right after doing this Steam now doesn't launch anymore. libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable, amongst other error messages all related to libGL

Answer (score 1):

Actually,Ubuntu recognizes your card.The problem here is that your gtx 980M card is very new.And there is no graphics driver that supports your card in the UBUNTU repository.
your only option is to install the latest driver from the NVIDIA,which is recomended by ubuntu

I think you didn't install it correctly.Installing nvidia drivers from nvidia website in ubuntu is little tricky.

here is  a detail explanation  of how to install it.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual

Comment: if you are stuck at any step,please ask me.i will try my level best.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. The files I need to edit don't exist so I skipped them. But after the X11 shutdown, I tried to log in to the shell using my normal details but these were rejected. Do I need to modify them slightly? I tried `username+password`, `username@machinename+password` with no success.

Comment: Ok I got past that stage, but then the X11 server restart wouldn't complete but kept hanging part way through. No problem I thought - I'll just reboot. Trouble is, now Ubuntu hangs during login. Any suggestions?

Comment: press ctrl+alt+F1 and login using username and password.then go to the directory you saved nvidia driver using cd command.

Comment: then run the command "sudo sh NVIDIA* --uninstall"

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to install nvidia newest drivers.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If using open source video drivers (fglrx, nouveau) generate xorg.conf
     to  improve performance.

```
 ctrl+alt+F1
 sudo service lightdm stop
 sudo Xorg -configure
 sudo mv xorg.conf.new xorg.conf
 sudo mv xorg.conf /etc/X11/
 sudo reboot
```

You can also launch the driver-settings from terminal

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Comment: Did you ever try to run these commands? It is almost all wrong.